# Kibana fails to pick up date from elasticsearch when I include the hour and minute

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm really stuggling to get this specific time format into elasticsearch so I can graph it in Kibana. I cannot change this format. My elasticsearch data and mapping is in this format:

**STEP 1: Setup Mapping**

```
PUT http://<>.com:5101/myindex6/_doc/1

{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd"
      },
        "data": {
        "type":   "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Step 2: Add Data**

```
PUT http://<>.com:5101/myindex6

{
  "test" : [ {
    "data" : "119050300",
    "date" : "10:00 2019-06-03"
  } ]
}
```

In Kibana it wont find this as a date and wont allow me to map it as one.  However, if I remove the time aspect and use the date, and do this instead, it works fine:

**Data**

```
{
  "test" : [ {
    "data" : "119050300",
    "date" : "2019-06-03"
  } ]
}
```

**Map**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      },
        "data": {
        "type":   "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to include the time and not have it break, so I can filter on time in kibana.

Comment: According to your example, if you've one document having ID1 whose content changes with respect to time then just you need to ```reindex``` the doc rather than ```remove & reindex```. Because, reindexing document will overwrite the document with new data.

Comment: This i a very common monitoring/logging scenario. Why don't you use one index per day (or other time range) and query just the indices within YTD? Older indicies can be removed if not needed any more... In this manner you'll be able to reduce the load in every component and gain more flexibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the difference between the mapping and the structure document that you are indexing. Also the endpoints you are using seems be swapped. Follow the steps below:

**1. Create index**

```
PUT myindex6
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd"
      },
        "data": {
        "type":   "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Index document**

```
POST myindex6/_doc/1
{
  "data": "119050300",
  "date": "10:00 2019-06-03"
}
```

Notice the endpoints used to create index and then to index a document. Also notice the structure of document is in line with the mapping. In your case you are indexing a document with a `test` field which is an array of object with fields `data` and `date`. This structure doesn't match to the mapping created in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed in the above answer, the data which you are indexing doesn't match with the mapping created. What you need to do is update your mapping with test field as nested.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "test": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "date": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd"
                },
                "data": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

And then re-index your data. The date field will appear in Kibana after that.

Comment: Just be aware that if you map `test` as nested, you won't be able to search in the Kibana Discover view.

Comment: It will be available as the nested field.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has already pointed out, your index mapping differs from your data, so you need to update the mapping. I would highly suggest revising Elasticsearch's [index mapping guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) to get a good understanding of mappings and their effect on the data indexed.

On another note, I saw you are still using mapping types. If you are just getting started with your ES use cases, it will be good to avoid using them as they will be deprecated and eventually removed from ES [[source]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/removal-of-types.html).

Answer (score 0):

You've got it all right, except one single tiny thing. In your mapping you specify the date format as being `epoch_millis` but in your document the datetime is specified in `epoch_second`.

So you have two choices:

1. Either you keep the mapping as it is and multiply all your date times by a factor of 1000
2. Or you change your mapping with `"format": "epoch_second"` and keep your data as it is.

In any case, you need to reload your index pattern in Kibana afterwards and it will work. Note that I tested this on Kibana 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I think it will work.

```
PUT http://<>.com:5101/myindex6/_doc/1

{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      },
        "data": {
        "type":   "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
PUT http://<>.com:5101/myindex6

{
  "test" : [ {
    "data" : "119050300",
    "date" : "2019-06-03T10:00:00Z"
  } ]
}
```